# How to run test cases in MS Excel from Selenium IDE?

Tags: testing, selenium, testautomationfx

How to run test cases in MS Excel from Selenium? Any books available to study Selenium test automation?

Comment: Are you asking "how can I test an Excel based application" or "can I test a Web application using data from Excel"

Comment: run selenium tests from data in MS Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Selenium to test MS Excel. That is, Selenium supports browser automation only, not automation of thick client apps, like Excel.

However, if you are talking about using MS Excel spreadsheets to data-drive your Selenium tests - that is, use Excel as input data for Selenium tests - that is possible.

Comment: yeah whatever u say in the later part (i.e MS Excel spreadsheets to data-drive my Selenium tests)  is right

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is geared up for testing web applications, so i'm struggling to see what your requirements are, or why you'd want to use it with Excel (/shudder).

You might want to consider Sikuli (http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/)

Answer (score 0):

Since Selenium RC has APIs of several languages, e.g. java, PHP, ruby, c#...e.t.c
So what you can do is using "excel reader" API from the language you adapt (e.g. java), then feed the data into selenium APIs.
Furthermore, you can use test framework that have data provider (e.g. testng) that can read test data from external sources, e.g. csv, xml...e.t.c
FYR